# How to assign multiple variables different values using one function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a series of arrays, each containing 20 different strings, basically like this:

```
const str1a = [
"Text",
"Different text",
"etc",
...
];

const str1b = [
"something else",
"more options",
"and more",
...
];
```

Etc, etc. Currently I use the following code to pick a random string from each array and concatenate them (this is for a poetry generator):

```
const generatorDiv = document.querySelector("#generator");

function writePoem () {
  let i = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let j = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let k = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let l = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let m = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let n = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let o = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let p = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  let q = Math.floor(21*Math.random());
  generatorDiv.innerHTML = str1a[i] + str1b[j] + str1c[k] + str1d[l] + "<br />" +
    str2a[m] + str2b[n] + str2c[o] + str2d[p] + str2e[q];
}

writePoem ();
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is (forgive me if this has been asked, I've tried a bunch of search parameters but feel as though I'm not using the right words)...

Is there some way to simplify all that let i, let j, let k...?

This was my best attempt, but it's not doing the trick:

```
function pickStr () {
  Math.floor(21*Math.random());
}

const randomnessStorage = [i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q];

for (let a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
  let randomnessStorage[a] = pickStr();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need the random numbers stored after you generate the div content?

Comment: you should `return` value in your pickStr function.. it's not returning any value just executing the Math function

Comment: Don't use twenty variables with arrays. Use one array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were going in the right direction. Add a `return` statement in `pickStr` function and update your `writePoem` function like following:

```
function pickStr () {
  return Math.floor(21*Math.random());
}

function writePoem () {
  generatorDiv.innerHTML = str1a[pickStr()] + str1b[pickStr()] + str1c[pickStr()] + str1d[pickStr()] + "<br />" +
    str2a[pickStr()] + str2b[pickStr()] + str2c[pickStr()] + str2d[pickStr()] + str2e[pickStr()];
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much. There's good suggestions in the other answers too, but this solves my problem exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was nearly right.

You did not return anything in `pickStr`.

- Get a random index in the range of the array `Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)`
- Pick a string

---

```js
const str1a = [
  "Can I",
  "Did it",
  "Was it"
];

const str1b = [
  "follow",
  "catch",
  "drop"
];

const str1c = [
  "an apple",
  "a car",
  "the truck"
];

const str1d = [
  "flying",
  "driving",
  "chewing"
];

function pickStr(arr) {
  if (arr) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[randomIndex];
  } else {
    return "-Array Null-";
  }
}

function writePoem() {
  let div = document.querySelector('#poem-container');
  let poemTemplate = `${pickStr(str1a)} ${pickStr(str1b)} ${pickStr(str1c)} ${pickStr(str1d)}`;
  div.innerHTML = poemTemplate;
}

writePoem();
```

```html
<div id="poem-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store your arrays in an array and create an es6 `pickstr` function that will return a random floored number.

```
 function writePoem () {
 let pickstr = () => Math.random() * 21 | 0,
 output = [str1a, str1b, str1c, str1d, str2a, str2b, str2c, str2d, str2e].map(str=>str[pickstr()]); 
 output.splice(4,0, "<br />")
 generatorDiv.innerHTML = output.join("");
 }

 writePoem ();
```

```js
const str1a = ["one.", "two.", "three.", "four."],
  str1b = ["five.", "six.", "seven.", "eight."],
  str1c = ["nine.", "ten.", "eleven.", "twelve."]; let generatorDiv = document.querySelector("#gendiv");

function writePoem() {
  let pickstr = () => Math.random() * 4 | 0,
  output =  [str1a, str1b, str1c, str1a, str1b, str1c].map(str => str[pickstr()]);
  output.splice(3,0, "<br/>");
  generatorDiv.innerHTML = output.join("");
}

writePoem();
```

```html
<div id="gendiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you then I would modify the structure and make it an **array of object** instead of multiple separate **array's**:

```
var str = [{
    'str1a': ["Text",
      "Different text",
      "etc",
    ]
  },
  { 'str1b': [...] },
  { 'str1c': [...] },
  { 'str1d': [...] }
];
```

Then I generate the random poem this way:

```js
const generatorDiv = document.querySelector("#generator");
var str = [{
    'str1a': ["Text",
      "Different text",
      "etc",
    ]
  },
  {
    'str1b': [
      "something else",
      "more options",
      "and more",
    ]
  },
  {
    'str1c': [
      "anything else",
      "les options",
      "or more",
    ]
  },
  {
    'str1d': [
      "else",
      "less",
      "more",
    ]
  }
];

function pickStr(arr) {

  let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[ran];

}
result = [];
str.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {

  for (var key in item) {
    result.push(pickStr(item[key]))
  }
}
console.log(result.join(' '))
generatorDiv.innerHTML = result.join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="generator"></div>
```